# serialization in java RMI

Tags: java, serialization, interface, rmi

I'm writing an application in Java using RMI. I have a couple of classes that implement an interface I've written. Why can't I just make that interface extend the Serializable interface, so that the two classes implementing it would be in turn serializable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that RMI checks the inheritance chain, it's easy enough to just add implements Serializable to each class anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your interface extend the [Serializable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interafce and all your classes implementing your interface will be implementing the `Serializable` interface as well.
This is a good read on making a class `Serializable` - [Java RMI: Serialization](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/JavaRMI_10/index.html?page=3)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but I had to make the two classes implement Serializable in order for them to work.

Comment: There are some very strange statements in that O'Reilly book. For example, equals() and hashCode() have nothing to do with serialization and aren't required to make a class Serializable.

Comment: @Rocky Triton: Hmm. Lots of Java books are from 2001, even one of mine ;-) Practically nothing has changed in RMI or Serialization since then. If a book is wrong it is wrong, nothing to do with publication date. Truth is not a function of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can. Having the interface extend Serializable is sufficient. From the language point of view this is entirely equivalent to having the implementing classes implement Serializable.